# How do transfer a list from one site to another site?

Tags: 2010

I have a list , I want transfer it to another site .

**Provided that the Created by and Modified by field value does not change.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `SharePoint 2010 Management Shell` you can transfer list from one site to another

1- Run the `SharePoint 2010 Management Shell` as administrator
2- Export your list from you source site using this command

```
export-spweb -Identity http://YOUR_SERVER_NAME/ -path C:\PATH_TO_SAVE_EXPORTED_FILE.cmp -itemurl "/Lists/YOUR_LIST_NAME"
```

3- Import the exported list to the destination site using this command

```
Import-SPWeb -Identity http://SERVER_NAME/ -Path C:\Lists\PATH_TO_SAVE_EXPORTED_FILE.cmp
```